# TypeError: res.json is not a function at CustomerComponent

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

```
GetFromServer(){
  this.http.get("http://localhost:3000/Customers")
      .subscribe(res=>this.SuccessGet(res),res=>this.Error(res));
}
Error(res:any){
  console.debug(res.json());
}
Success(res:any){
  this.GetFromServer();
}
SuccessGet(res:any){
  this.GetFromServer();
}
```

I got TypeError:

> res.json is not a function at CustomerComponent in console

I'm expecting the values whatever enter through UI in db.json file

Answer (score -1):

It's `JSON.parse(res)`, not `res.json()`.

And anyway, the error is already an object, so you don't even need that.

Comment: then what changes should I make in my code?
if I type JSON.parse(res) then I got SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'T', "TypeError:"... is not valid JSON
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at CustomerComponent.Error

Comment: @VaishaliNimbalkar `res` is probably a string. Just use `console.debug(res)`